# How can I search in Has Parent Query

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-5

I've been trying to search through has parent query but I am not been able to do it as I can't find proper procedure to do it. For example I have roles table and I have user table and I am using 1 for administrator role and in user table I have an attribute with the name of user_role and I've record with user_role =1 how can I do mapping using has parent query and search accordingly.

Thanks,
Ali.

https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/5.5/mapping-parent-field.html

couldn't understand fully.

Comment: So what have you tried? Minimal examples for the mapping and parent child documents would be a good start or what failed.

Comment: Can you please provide me a precise example of has_parent example, because I am unable to understand how to do has_parent example in the document.

Comment: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/5.5/query-dsl-has-parent-query.html has an example query. But without your mapping and sample docs we can't give you a specific example (other than what is in the docs anyway).

Comment: In that case can you please proved me the mapping of has_parent that is not provided in the above given link? because I may not understand without it.. I'll appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

Let's take the mapping and sample data from https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/5.5/mapping-parent-field.html:

```
PUT my_index
{
  "mappings": {
    "my_parent": {},
    "my_child": {
      "_parent": {
        "type": "my_parent" 
      }
    }
  }
}

PUT my_index/my_parent/1 
{
  "text": "This is a parent document"
}

PUT my_index/my_child/2?parent=1 
{
  "text": "This is a child document"
}

PUT my_index/my_child/3?parent=1&refresh=true 
{
  "text": "This is another child document"
}
```

The query on the same page, gets the single parent doc since both child documents are matching:

```
GET my_index/my_parent/_search
{
  "query": {
    "has_child": { 
      "type": "my_child",
      "query": {
        "match": {
          "text": "child document"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

With some slight modifications you'll be able to search on the `has_parent`:

```
GET my_index/my_child/_search
{
  "query": {
    "has_parent": { 
      "parent_type": "my_parent",
      "query": {
        "match": {
          "text": "parent"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

PS: This is changing quite a bit in 6.x. If possible I'd move to 6 now to avoid the upgrading pain later on.